# Posting data via JSON when checkbox id/name contains hyphen

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to use postUserData so that if a person fills in and submits a form on one page of my website, it submits the data to a form on a different page on my website.

It all worked until I introduced a checkbox named writerep to my form, as my CMS autogenerates the checkbox name on the final form (in this case, the catchy "custom-1798_0", and because that ID/name contains a hyphen, it breaks the JSON. Other checkbox without hyphen works fine. Code below:

```
    $('#user_info_form').validate({
submitHandler: function submitHandler(form, e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var firstname = e.target.firstname.value;
    var lastname = e.target.lastname.value;
    var email = e.target.email.value;
    var country = e.target.country.value;
    var writerep = e.target.writerep.checked;
    var emailopt = e.target.emailopt.checked;

    userInfo = {
        firstname: firstname,
        lastname: lastname,
        email: email,
        country: country,
        custom-1798_0: writerep? 1 : 0,
        email_opt_in: emailopt ? 1 : 0
    };

    postUserData(userInfo, 'https://*********');
    nextSlide('.slide1');
},

rules: {
    firstname: "required",
    lastname: "required",
    country: "required",
    email: {
        required: true,
        email: true
    }
},
messages: {
    firstname: "Please enter your first name",
    lastname: "Please enter your last name",
    country: "Please select your country",
    email: {
        required: "Please enter your email address",
        email: "Please enter a valid email address"
    }
}
});
```

Without renaming the checkbox on the final form, which isn't possible due to CMS limitations, is there a way of making this work?

Comment: Is there a reason for not just changing the hyphen to an underscore?

Answer (score 0):

You have to quote property names that have special characters or spaces in them. Some are allowed like `$` and `_`  but `-` is not since it is also an operator

```
userInfo = {
    firstname: firstname,
    lastname: lastname,
    email: email,
    country: country,
    'custom-1798_0': writerep? 1 : 0,
    email_opt_in: emailopt ? 1 : 0
};
```

Comment: This has fixed the hyphen issue, but the data (whether checkbox is ticked or not) isn't passing through even though other checkbox below in exact same format is. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does it have  `name` attribute?

Comment: Yes, same as ID. I just restructured the form so now both ID and name of final checkbox are "custom-1799" rather than "custom-1798_0", but still not working.

Comment: So I've check the var UserInfo after submitting in the console and it's definitley collecting the data as I'm getting this in return:

country:"GB"
custom-1799:1
email:"******"
email_opt_in:1
firstname:"Georgia"
lastname:"O'Brien"

However when I export the form at the other end, it's picking up all the data (name, country, email optin checkbox etc.) but custom-1799 checkbox is blank. Is there any reason that putting the name of target checkbox for data in quotes like you suggested would prevent the data from passing through when posted?